# How can Iframes be optimized for search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt, iframe

If my site has an Iframe.  What is the best way to optimize this for search engines?

We want to keep the Iframe. I have read that blocking Iframes in *robot.txt* is a good way to go, but this seems rather pointless to me.

I also heard there is a way to notify Webmaster tools that Iframes exist. Has someone done this?

Comment: What is the purpose of your Iframe?  Does it have content that you want to have indexed?  Is it content from another site and you want to avoid duplicate content?    The SEO technique depends on what your Iframe is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Google says to handle it makes me think they don't appreciate iframes that much.

> Google supports frames and iframes to the extent that it can. Frames
>   can cause problems for search engines because they don't correspond to
>   the conceptual model of the web. In this model, one page displays only
>   one URL. Pages that use frames or iframes display several URLs (one
>   for each frame) within a single page. Google tries to associate framed
>   content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee
>   that we will.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en

From my experience, if you are showing inside an iframe, information that is indeed important and related to your original website, you'll be basically spreading the strength of your content.

There's some discussion about it here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/uQ8m1RPqgxw

Other article I found, says this:

> However, pages that utilize iFrames display multiple URLs for one lone
>   page, as every single iFrame has its own different URL. This is where
>   the problems begin. When Google crawls webpages with iFrames, the
>   search engine attempts to associate all the framed content with the
>   parent HTML document, or the page that contains all the iFrames. As
>   great as Google is, it isn’t perfect and it doesn’t always succeed.

http://www.audiencebloom.com/2014/01/google-known-crawl-iframes-website/

In MOZ there's a discussion about the subject that might be interesting: http://moz.com/community/q/iframes-seo

The best way to optimize the iframe is actually have the least content possible there. What I mean is that if you have a big page with text and a Form, try to remove the text and leave only the form while inserting the content on the original page.

There's no way to tell Webmaster Tools you have an iframe, however there's nothing forbidding you to add it as a new property.

My advice: don't use it unless you're really forced to.